Add static url slug before child post in custom post type in WordPress
Wanted hierarchy:
https://website.com/{category_name}/{parent_post_slug}/static_slug/{child_post_slug}
Examples:
https://website.com/cars/volvo/machine/volvo-1
https://website.com/motorcycle/bmw/machine/bmx
I have a custom post type "vehicles" with custom taxonomy "vehicles-types"
Does it possible to implement it with rewrite rule or another hook?
Thanks
